# Java Date Time conversion to given timezone

Tags: java, datetime, timezone, datetime-format, timezone-offset

I have a DateTime in the format of `Tue, 30 Apr 2019 16:00:00 +0800` which is `RFC 2822 formatted date`

I need to convert this to the given timezone in the DateTime which is +0800

So if i summarized,

```
DateGiven = Tue, 30 Apr 2019 16:00:00 +0800
DateWanted = 01-05-2019 00:00:00
```

How can i achieve this in Java? 
I have tried the below code but it gives 08 hours lesser than the current time which is

```
30-04-2019 08:00:00
```

### Code i tried

```
String pattern = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z";
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
Date startDate = format.parse(programmeDetails.get("startdate").toString());

//Local time zone   
 SimpleDateFormat dateFormatLocal = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss");

//Time in GMT
Date dttt= dateFormatLocal.parse( dateFormatGmt.format(startDate) );
```

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `OffsetDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with the help of @ole v.v's explanation  i have separated the datetime value for two 
1. time 
2. timezone

then i used this coding to extract the datetime which is related to the given timezone

```
//convert datetime to give timezone 
    private static String DateTimeConverter (String timeVal, String timeZone)
    {
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");


    SimpleDateFormat offsetDateFormat2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");

        offsetDateFormat2.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZone));
        String result =null;
        try {
            result = offsetDateFormat2.format(format.parse(timeVal));
        } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You are on right approach but just use java-8 date time API module, first create `DateTimeFormatter` with the input format representation

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");
```

And then use `OffsetDateTime` to parse string with offset

```
OffsetDateTime dateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse("Tue, 30 Apr 2019 16:00:00 +0800",formatter);
```

And the call the `toLocalDateTime()` method to get the local time

```
LocalDateTime localDateTime = dateTime.toLocalDateTime();  //2019-04-30T16:00
```

If you want the output in particular format again you can use [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)

```
localDateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)   //2019-04-30T16:00:00
```

**Note :** As @Ole V.V pointed in comment, after parsing the input string into [util.Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) you are getting the `UTC` time

> The class Date represents a specific instant in time, with millisecond precision.

So now if you convert the parsed date time into `UTC` you get `2019-04-30T08:00Z` without offset, so you can use [withOffsetSameInstant](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#atZoneSameInstant-java.time.ZoneId-) to convert it into any particular timezone

```
dateTime.withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. i have created the coding and posted as an answer for the objective that i was trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

You misunderstood. According to RFC 2822 `+0800` means that an offset of 8 hours 0 minutes *has already* been applied to the time compared to UTC. So the output you got was the correct GMT time.

### java.time

I recommend you skip the old and outdated classes `SimpleDateFOrmat` and `Date`. It’s much nicer to work with java.time, the modern Java date and time API. Furthermore it has the RFC format built in, so we don’t need to write our own formatter.

```
    OffsetDateTime parsedDateTime = OffsetDateTime
            .parse("Tue, 30 Apr 2019 16:00:00 +0800",
                    DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME);
    
    ZonedDateTime dateTimeInSingapore
            = parsedDateTime.atZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Asia/Singapore"));
    System.out.println("In Singapore: " + dateTimeInSingapore);
    
    OffsetDateTime dateTimeInGmt
            = parsedDateTime.withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
    System.out.println("In GMT:       " + dateTimeInGmt);
```

Output:

> ```
> In Singapore: 2019-04-30T16:00+08:00[Asia/Singapore]
> In GMT:       2019-04-30T08:00Z
> ```

The built-in formatter is named `RFC_1123_DATE_TIME` because the same format is used in multiple Requests for Comments (RFCs).

### Links

- [RFC 2822 Internet Message Format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822)
- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.

Comment: Thank you very much for your nice explanation. it really helped me to construct my coding. anyways i wanted to change the time  Tue, 30 Apr 2019 16:00:00  to  01-05-2019 00:00:00 by adding +0800 as you said i misunderstood that the time is not converted when its RFC. i have changed my coding to send the timezone separately and time seperately. and developed the code in the answer.