# How can I get UTC Instant of startDate and endDate of today in a specific time zone ("Europe/Paris")

Tags: java, spring, date, datetime, localization

I want to get the UTC instant (since my DB is storing in UTC) from Java (which is also in UTC) of a particular time zone, this is what I have tried so far:

```java
    public static Instant getStartOfTheDayDateTime(Instant instant, String zoneId) {

        ZonedDateTime zoned = instant.atZone(ZONE_ID_TO_ZONE_MAP.get(zoneId));
        ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of(zoneId);

        return zoned.toLocalDate().atStartOfDay(zone).toInstant();
//        ZonedDateTime startOfTheDay = zoned.withHour(0)
//                .withMinute(0)
//                .withSecond(0)
//                .withNano(0);
//
//        return startOfTheDay.toInstant();
    }

    public static Instant getEndOfTheDayDateTime(Instant instant, String zoneId) {
        ZonedDateTime zoned = instant.atZone(ZONE_ID_TO_ZONE_MAP.get(zoneId));
        ZonedDateTime endOfTheDay = zoned.withHour(0)
                .withMinute(0)
                .withSecond(0)
                .withNano(0)
                .plusDays(1);
        return endOfTheDay.toInstant();

    }
```

Every attempt shows:

```
2020-04-10 22:00:00.0(Timestamp), 2020-04-11 22:00:00.0(Timestamp)
```

- Is this the start/end of the day UTC time in Europe/Paris zone ?
- I was expecting to have `2020-04-11 02:00:00.0(Timestamp), 2020-04-12 02:00:00.0(Timestamp)`

Comment: I don't see any old-fashioned `Timestamp` in your code, so there must be something you are not showing us? But yes, given that the timestamps print in UTC, they denote the start and end of the day in Paris.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java Date Time conversion to given timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58830202/java-date-time-conversion-to-given-timezone)

Comment: Setting the hour of day to 0 is not always correct for getting the start of the day. There are occasions where summer time (DST) start at midnight in some time zone, so the first moment of the day is 01:00. Your use of `atStartOfDay()` is the correct and bullet-proof way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now, Paris is on summer time: UTC+2.  Paris is 'ahead' of UTC by 2 hours.

So 00:00:00 in Paris local time is 22:00:00 UTC.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this the start/end of the day UTC time in Europe/Paris zone ?

Yes. Europe/Paris is in daylight savings time. Midnight in Paris occurred at 22:00 UTC time.

> I was expecting to have 2020-04-11 02:00:00.0(Timestamp), 2020-04-12 02:00:00.0(Timestamp)

That's not right, 02:00 UTC would have been 04:00 in Paris time.

Answer (score 2):

## Ask programmatically if a moment is in DST

> Is this the start/end of the day UTC time in Europe/Paris zone ?

Get start of day.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Europe/Paris" );
ZonedDateTime zdtStartOfDay = instant.atZone( z ).toLocalDate().atStartOfDay( z ) ;
```

Ask if that moment is in DST for that zone.

```
ZoneRules rules = z.getRules();
boolean isDst = rules.isDaylightSavings( zdtStartOfDay.toInstant() );
```

## Pass date-time objects rather than mere strings

> `public static Instant getStartOfTheDayDateTime(Instant instant, String zoneId)`

I suggest you ask the calling programmer to pass a valid `ZoneId` object rather than a mere string. It should not be the job of this method to validate their string input. If it is reasonable to expect a `Instant` then it is also reasonable to expect a `ZoneId`.

```
 public static Instant getStartOfTheDayDateTime(Instant instant, ZoneID zoneId )
```

## Half-Open

> `public static Instant getEndOfTheDayDateTime(Instant instant, String zoneId) {`

Trying to determine the last moment of the day is impossible because of infinitely divisible last second.

Also this approach to defining a span of time is awkward. It makes abutting multiple spans tricky. Various software systems and protocols differ in their resolution of that last fractional second, using milliseconds, microseconds, nanoseconds, or some other fraction.

The common practice in date-time handling is to track a span of time using the Half-Open approach. In Half-Open, the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*.

So a full day begins with the first moment of the day and runs up to, but does not include, the first moment of the *next* day.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Europe/Paris" );
ZonedDateTime zdtStartOfDay = instant.atZone( z ).toLocalDate().atStartOfDay( z ) ; 
ZonedDateTime zdtStartOfNextDay = instant.atZone( z ).toLocalDate().plusDays( 1 ).atStartOfDay( z ) ;
```

You might want to break that code out to more lines, for easier reading/debugging.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;  // Or passed in. 
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Europe/Paris" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
LocalDate ld = zdt.toLocalDate() ;
LocalDate ldNextDay = ld.plusDays( 1 ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdtStartOfNextDay = ldNextDay.atStartOfDay( z ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/on5NRv). For example:

```
System.out.println( instant ) ;             // 2020-04-13T00:15:25.235341Z
System.out.println( zdt ) ;                 // 2020-04-13T02:15:25.235341+02:00[Europe/Paris]
System.out.println( ld ) ;                  // 2020-04-13
System.out.println( ldNextDay ) ;           // 2020-04-14
System.out.println( zdtStartOfNextDay ) ;   // 2020-04-14T00:00+02:00[Europe/Paris]
```

### *ThreeTen-Extra* `Interval`

If you do this kind of work with spans of time often, then I suggest adding the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library to your project. That library includes the [`Interval`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html) class to track a span-of-time as a a pair of `Instant` objects.

```
Interval interval = Interval.of( zdtStartOfDay.toInstant() , zdtStartOfNextDay.toInstant() ) ;
```

You can then make use the several handy comparison methods such as `abuts`, `contains`, `encloses`, `intersection`, `overlaps`, and `union`.

## `Timestamp`

Never use the `java.sql.Timestamp` class. This class is part of the terrible date-time classes that shipped with the earliest versions of Java. These classes are now legacy, supplanted entirely by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310 and built into Java 8 and later.

As of JDBC 4.2 we can exchange *java.time* objects with a database. Use `getObject` and `setObject` and `updateObject`.

The JDBC spec oddly requires support for `OffsetDateTime` but not the more commonly used `Instant` and `ZonedDateTime`. Your particular driver *may* support these other types. If not, convert.

Retrieval from database.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
Instant instant = odt.toInstant() ;
```

Sending to the database.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , odt ) ;
```

Comment: `ZonedDateTime zdtStartOfDay = instant.atZone( z ).toLocalDate().atStartOfDay( z ) ; ` is not returning a ZonedDateTime, it is returninng a LocaleDateTime, which makes the lines wrong, what's your opinion about it ?

Comment: @DimitriKopriwa See [`LocalDate.atStartOfDay` Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#atStartOfDay(java.time.ZoneId)). If you pass a `ZoneId`, you get a `ZonedDateTime` object. If you [pass no arguments](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#atStartOfDay()), you get a `LocalDateTime` (which has no concept of time zone or offset, and cannot represent a moment, is not a point on the timeline).

Comment: I did copy past your snipet which already pass a zoneId, which I am having in my current function and toLocalDate on it doesn't not return a ZonedDateTime. It return a LocalDate.

Comment: @DimitriKopriwa See for yourself, with [code running live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/on5NRv). Calling `LocalDate::atStartOfDay( ZoneId )` returns a `ZonedDateTime`. Run this:  `Instant.now().atZone( ZoneId.of( "Europe/Paris" ) ).toLocalDate().atStartOfDay( ZoneId.of( "Europe/Paris" ) ).getClass().getCanonicalName()`  ➡  java.time.ZonedDateTime

Comment: @DimitriKopriwa I added another code snippet to the Answer, breaking the long lines into multiple lines. The class types are more obvious that way.