# Is date in the target timezone in ISO 8601?

Tags: timezone, timezone-offset, iso8601

I trying to parse a date in **ISO 8601** format and some moments aren't clear for me.

For example, I have the next date: `2020-04-16T07:16:34.858215+03:00` in `Europe/Moscow` timezone.

Does it mean `07:16` in Moscow time or `10:16`? I mean do I need to add 3 hours to date or date is in Moscow time already and timezone just shows how it diffs from UTC?

**P.S.** I tried to find information about it but everywhere is just common format description without details.

Comment: Related/similar: [Java Date Time conversion to given timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58830202/java-date-time-conversion-to-given-timezone)

Comment: @OleV.V. Thank you for the link!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The time specified is the local time, so `2020-04-16T07:16:34.858215+03:00`  means 7:16am in Moscow, or 4:16am UTC.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) has a good example which clarifies things to at least some extent:

> The following times all refer to the same moment: "18:30Z", "22:30+04", "1130−0700", and "15:00−03:30". Nautical time zone letters are not used with the exception of Z. To calculate UTC time one has to subtract the offset from the local time, e.g. for "15:00−03:30" do 15:00 − (−03:30) to get 18:30 UTC.

It's really unfortunate that ISO-8601 talks about this as a time zone, when it's only a UTC offset - it definitely *doesn't* specify the actual time zone. (So you can't tell what the local time will be one minute later, for example.)

Comment: Thank you for answer! I read Russian Wiki version, unfortunately, there was not so many details.